# Change Activity Owner after changing Account owner

Tags: tasks, ownership

I need to change Open activities owner from existing owner to new owner. I started of this process by changing the Account name to the new owner. But the open activities are not on the old Account owner name. I used Demand tools to do the account transfer. Have any of you guys faced a similar problem?

Answer (score 1):

[From Knowledge Article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000187186&language=en_US)

It should first be noted that if you only need to transfer open activities for the Lead and/or Account objects than one option should be to utilize the Mass Transfer Wizard for those objects.  When record ownership changes for a Lead or Account the associated Open Activities that are owned by the same user are automatically transferred to the new owner (See [Mass Transferring Records](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_transfer.htm&language=en_US))

[image]